# Regex JavaScript String and store results into variables

Tags: javascript, regex

If I had a string with three values that is delimited by spaces, now I want to store these three values in three variables or maybe an array, how to do?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Split).

For example:

```
var variables = delimited_string.split(/\s+/);
```

If you know it is separated by a single space, avoid using a regular expression with the following:

```
var variables = delimited_string.split(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it: I use String.split(pattern)

```
var str = "I am confused".split(/\s/g)
```

Comment: Are you answering your own question?

Comment: The `g` modifier is unnecessary.